# Button doesn't work upon changing position

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

Out of nowhere, **my button stopped working**. I tried to narrow it down to what was causing the issue, it happens whenever I add the following piece of code in my `css` -

```
#filler{
    position:relative;
    left:340px;
    top:85px
}
```

It was working all this time and is suddenly non functional, but only when I try to position it. 
Here is all my code for reference:

```js
function myFunction() {
  $('#Asterisk').empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    for (var a = i; a < 7; a++) {

      $('#Asterisk').append("*");
    }

    $('#Asterisk').append("<br>");


  }


}
```

```css
#Obelix {
  border: 8px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  top: 100px
}

#Getafix {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 75px;
  bottom: 126px
}

#Asterisk {
  position: relative;
  right: 325px;
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}

#mainwrapper {
  height: 4000px;
  width: 4000px;
  position: relative
}

#filler {
  position: relative;
  left: 340px;
  top: 85px
}

#filler {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

#filler:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41
}

#filler:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/looping.css">


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="looping.js">
  </script>
</head>
<div id="mainwrapper">

  <body>
    <button id="filler" onclick="myFunction()"> Fill in the box </button>
    <div id="imgbox"> </div>
    <div id="Obelix">
      <div id="Asterisk"> </div>
      <div id="Getafix"> </div>
    </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your #Getafix div is above the button, as soon as you position it. You may use z-index to change this order. E.g.

```
button {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

edit: I added a light nearly transparent background-color to #Getafix, so you may see its positioning. In case using z-index is no option for you (as you need it to be visually above the button), you could use `pointer-events: none;` on the #Getafix div. This causes all click-events to be ignored by #Getafix and instead passed to the underlying button. Unfortunately the brower support for poiner-events is mediocre (no ie10 or below support): http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

```js
function myFunction(){
  $('#Asterisk').empty();
  for(var i =0;i<7;i++) { 
   
     for(var a=i;a<7;a++) { 

  $('#Asterisk').append("*");
    
   }
   
   
  $('#Asterisk').append("<br>");
  
   
  }
  
 
     }
```

```css
#Obelix{
    border:8px solid black;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    left:250px;
    top:100px}

    #Getafix{
 width:400px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    left:75px;
    bottom:126px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1); /* making the #Getafix div position visible */
    }
 

    #Asterisk{
    position:relative;
    right:325px;
    top:10px;
    transform:rotate(180deg)
    }

    #mainwrapper{
 height:4000px;
    width:4000px;
    position:relative}
   
    #filler{
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
    left:340px;
    top:85px
    }
   
    #filler {
    padding: 15px 25px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
    }


    #filler:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

    #filler:active {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
    box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
    transform: translateY(4px);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

      <html>
   
      <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
 href="css/looping.css">
 
    
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">                       
     </script> 
     <script src="looping.js"> </script>
     </head>
     <div id="mainwrapper"> 
     <body>
     <button  id="filler" onclick="myFunction()"> Fill in the box </button>
     <div id="imgbox"> </div>
     <div id="Obelix"> 
     <div id="Asterisk"> </div>  
     <div id="Getafix">  </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining what was wrong. Wasn't aware that the Getafix div was positioned above my button.

Comment: All answers helped to solve my issue, but this particular one was able to help me understand exactly what I did wrong. Nonetheless, I'd like to thank everyone for their help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the stack order of the button , I have added `z-index:99;` to the `#filler` now its working

```js
function myFunction() {
  $('#Asterisk').empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (var a = i; a < 7; a++) {
      $('#Asterisk').append("*");
    }
    $('#Asterisk').append("<br>");
  }
}
```

```css
#Obelix {
  border: 8px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
  top: 100px
}

#Getafix {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 75px;
  bottom: 126px
}

#Asterisk {
  position: relative;
  right: 325px;
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}

#mainwrapper {
  height: 4000px;
  width: 4000px;
  position: relative
}

#filler {
  position: relative;
  left: 340px;
  top: 85px;
  z-index:99;
}

#filler {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
}

#filler:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41
}

#filler:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="mainwrapper">

  <body>
    <button id="filler" onclick="myFunction()"> Fill in the box </button>
    <div id="imgbox"> </div>
    <div id="Obelix">
      <div id="Asterisk"> </div>
      <div id="Getafix"> </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix div element (#Getafix) position or add a z-index to button element (#filler).

Currently div element (#Getafix) is overlapped width button element and div element catch click event.

Answer (score 1):

You button is under `#Getafix` element, so it can't be pressed.

You can increase `z-index` of `#Asterisk` element or set `pointer-events` of `#Getafix` to `none` as in snippet below.

```js
 function myFunction(){
  $('#Asterisk').empty();
  for(var i =0;i<7;i++) { 
   
     for(var a=i;a<7;a++) { 

  $('#Asterisk').append("*");
    
   }
   
   
  $('#Asterisk').append("<br>");
  
   
  }
  
 
     }
```

```css
#Obelix{
    border:8px solid black;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    left:250px;
    top:100px}

    #Getafix{
 width:400px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    left:75px;
    bottom:126px;
    pointer-events: none;
    }
 

    #Asterisk{
    position:relative;
    right:325px;
    top:10px;
    transform:rotate(180deg)
    }

    #mainwrapper{
 height:4000px;
    width:4000px;
    position:relative}
   
    #filler{
    position:relative;
    left:340px;
    top:85px
    }
   
    #filler {
    padding: 15px 25px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
    }


    #filler:hover {background-color: #3e8e41}

    #filler:active {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
    box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
    transform: translateY(4px);
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>

      <html>
   
      <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
 href="css/looping.css">
 
    
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">                       
     </script> 
     <script src="looping.js"> </script>
     </head>
     <div id="mainwrapper"> 
     <body>
     <button  id="filler" onclick="myFunction()"> Fill in the box </button>
     <div id="imgbox"> </div>
     <div id="Obelix"> 
     <div id="Asterisk"> </div>  
     <div id="Getafix">  </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already got your answer. Just a suggestion. Don't wrap your body element inside other `div`. The `<body></body>` should be the root for your documents body.

Comment: oops, i don't normally do that.Honest mistake,thanks.

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Add `top: 100px;` and remove `bottom: 126px;` in `#Getafix` css.

```
#Getafix {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 75px;
    /* bottom: 126px; */
    top: 100px;
}
```